# Static footer with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any replacement for `navbar-static-bottom`? Currently I set my footer like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="navbar-text pull-left">&copy; 2015 by Someone. </p>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/Default"><strong>Test</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Does anyone have an example of a static footer? That is, a footer that behaves the same way `navbar-static-top` does? Everything I try keeps failing. 
I could not find anything on this. I must be missing something cus it seems like such a common alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the footer, set

```
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%
```

example here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Comment: If you resize the window to a very small size, you will see that the footer behaves differently than the navbar. Navbar is fixed and will stay at the top of the window even when you scroll down. Footer is only visible when you scroll down. See the other answer if you want the footer to behave like the navbar (fixed).

Comment: true.  `position: fixed;` is often better.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will put your footer to the bottom of the page. If you want a sticky footer at the bottom of the window above possibly longer content, you need this:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: A fixed navbar is not what I am looking for.